WSUS client reports to server but does not download any updates
I have a WSUS Server (Windows Server 2016) and a Windows 10 22H2 client. The WSUS server receives updates via an external connected server since this server is within a stand-alone environment. All updates have been transferred from the external to the internal server as well as the metadata. Updates have been approved and declined accordingly and maintenance has been ran in the WID/SQL database. I have configured everything by group policy and the client is reporting correctly to the WSUS server and is seen as needing certain updates but when I click on the "Check for updates" button on the client, it says it is "You're up to date". I've made sure that Dual Scan is disable and everything is configured to not go to WU for anything but I do not know what's missing for the client to see updates and pull updates.
Attached is everything I could gather as far as logs and other screenshots but I do not know where else to look for faults. One thing I noticed is what I could not download the iuident.cab and wuident.cab from the get go but after allowing downloads on the browser I could but as an insecure download. I do not know where to whitelist this to be able to download them without prompts. Also, are these cab files needed (or are going to be installed) on the clients in any way to be able to see updates? How do these cab files works?
Client Windows Update Screen
Client WU Logs 1
Client WU Logs 2
Client WU Logs 3
Client WU Logs 4
wuident.cab download warning
iuident.cab download warning

What KB update on the WSUS server are you expecting the Windows 10 22H2 client to download?

The uident.cab and wuident.cab warnings in Edge are normal and occur because they're HTTP instead of HTTPS downloads. Edge is warning you that the connection/download could be tampered with because they're not encrypted. If you want to solve this, you can convert your WSUS to SSL.
First, make sure that all of the necessary files in WSUS have been approved and are fully downloaded with this icon:

Next, you'll want to rule out an issue with WSUS itself, can the WSUS server connect to itself for updates? If so, then you might have a client agent issue and you can reset the agent:
https://www.ajtek.ca/wsus/client-machines-not-reporting-to-wsus-properly/
Stop-Service -Name BITS, wuauserv -Force
Remove-ItemProperty -Name AccountDomainSid, PingID, SusClientId, SusClientIDValidation -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Item "$env:SystemRoot\SoftwareDistribution\" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-Service -Name BITS, wuauserv
wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow
(New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate).DetectNow()

If no-one can connect to the WSUS, you may need to uninstall and re-install your WSUS instance. If you're using WID, remember to delete the DB files before re-installing or you'll still have the corrupted data.
